# Can anyone tell my while my for loop in r is just running once?

Tags: r, for-loop

Can anyone tell my while my for loop in r is just running once? The script is just attempting to create csv files for a list of about 200 subfiles within about 5 major files. Here is my code :

```
ImpactGrid<- function(num, condition, CONDITION){


  #Set working directiory 

  for(i in num){

    if(i <10){
      filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID00000", i, ".txt", sep = "")
    }
    if(i >=10 & i < 100){
      filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID0000", i, ".txt", sep = "")
    }

    if(i>= 100){
      filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID000", i, ".txt", sep = "")
    }


con <- file(filename, "r")
data <- readLines(con)
close(con)
q <- data[21:length(data)] # removes non data before the data begins



Impactdata <- read.table(text = q, sep=',',fill=TRUE,colClasses='character',header = TRUE )

Savename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/",condition, "_csv_data/", condition,i, ".csv", sep = "")   



write.csv(Impactdata, Savename)  
x <- read.csv(paste("./EOBS DATA/",condition, "_csv_data/", condition,i, ".csv", sep = ""))  

return(head(x))
}
}
```

Comment: How do you call this function, with what arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to go from 1 to `num`, the code is:

```
for(i in 1:num)
```

`for` loops iterate over a vector but `num` has a length 1 so it iterates only 1 time.

You also need to remove the `return` statement from the body of the loop.  Otherwise, it will always exit the first time it hits return.

Answer (score 1):

While I think the 1:num is a good answer and may be a problem, it looks like the for loop encompasses everything including the last return() statement.  So even if num were a vector, it'd only loop once through all the code and return() from the function after one loop.